# Save data in list as a draft

Tags: javascript

I have a condition where a forms need to be filled out by the customer. In this scenario there are two different button below the form. One is submit and the another one is save. So the use of save button here is just to save the data as a draft, so that if the user clicks on saves, they can later on open their draft and fill out the whole form and then submit the data. So what approach should can I follow here to achieve this?

Should I create 2 lists with identical columns and run some kind of javascript or what?

Comment: Is it custom form developed in C# (using SSOM ), or OOTB , infopath or any other tool ?

Comment: @Gaurravs: the form is developed using Nintex Forms

Comment: If you are looking for generic approach lets say in C#, then we can help. but not specific to Nintex form

Answer (score 0):

I had this as a requirement before. What I did is I have embedded a javascript that would change the value of a column called **Action** in my list. So when the user clicks on the **Save** button, the value of the column would be **Save**; else, the value is **Submit**. Then based from this value, I've placed an **if-else** statement within a workflow [which automatically runs when the item has been created or changed] that would start an *approval process* [or whatever steps you would put in] once the value is **Submit**.